# How can I change 2D array elements with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to change only the place in the list called numbers.

So if is numbers=[4,8,11], I want to change 4>>field[0,5]=1,8>>field[0,9]=1,11>>field[1,0]=1

Number in list numbers are 0 to 100.
I run this,but it's says 'TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment'

How can I solve this? And is there better way to check each number and set 1 at 2D array?

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np

field = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=int)

def change_numbers(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        if 1 <= i <= 10:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[0,i] = 1
        elif 11 <= i <= 20:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[1,i] = 1
        elif 21 <= i <= 30:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[2,i] = 1
        elif 31 <= i <= 40:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[3,i] = 1
        elif 41 <= i <= 50:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[4,i] = 1
        elif 51 <= i <= 60:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[5,i] = 1
        elif 61 <= i <= 70:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[6,i] = 1
        elif 71 <= i <= 80:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[7,i] = 1
        elif 81 <= i <= 90:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[8,i] = 1
        elif 91 <= i <= 100:
            i -= 1
            p1_field[9,i] = 1
    print(field)
```

Comment: What is `p1_field`?

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. field == p1_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To define a function to change the elements of an array, it's better to put the array as an input of the function. This may explain the error message you encountered.
2. There is a better way to do the job you desired.

Here's the code:

```
def change_numbers(array, numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        array[(i - 1)//10, i-1] = 1
```

The last line basically does the whole long 'if' clauses. `(i - )//10` returns 0, 1, 2, ... for the conditions in your code.